# What previous results match/compare to Alireza Firouzja's 3000+ performance in the European Team Championships?

Tags: history, performance

Firouzja has just scored 8/9 against opposition with an average rating of 2664 - 7 wins and 2 draws. According to the video clip in [this tweet](https://twitter.com/jbmullon/status/1462534941196095489) his performance rating was 3017. According to [chess-results.com](http://chess-results.com/tnr583987.aspx?lan=1&art=9&turdet=YES&flag=30&snr=47) it was 3015. Either way a stunning performance.

Has anybody produced a similar level of chess in standard FIDE rated competitions, 3000+? If not which players have got closest?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

An unofficial list of the highest Tournament Performance Ratings (TPRs) on record in standard FIDE classical tournaments since 1970 is here: https://deletionpedia.org/en/List_of_highest_chess_Tournament_Performance_Ratings

Because this list was last updated in May 2015, high TPRs after that would not be included. However, I'm tentatively doubtful there has been a 3000+ rated performance since 2015. Usually Carlsen's best performance is thought to be Pearl Spring, Nanjing 2009, which barely crossed 3000. That's included on this list.

Adding in Firouzja, there are only 3 performances at 3000+:

1. Fabiano Caruana - St Louis, 2014 - 3098
2. Alireza Firouzja - ETCC, 2021 - 3015
3. Magnus Carlsen - Nanjing, 2009 - 3002

Not accounting for inflation, it appears Firouzja may have already surpassed Carlsen's highest-ever TPR. As you say, incredible stuff.

You might also find [Jeff Sonas' attempt to correct for inflation](https://en.chessbase.com/post/facts-and-figures-magnus-carlsen-s-performance-in-nanjing) interesting. (He concludes Karpov at Linares 1994 is the greatest tournament performance ever.) It's quite possible, given this article was written in the wake of Nanjing 2009, that similar analyses will be shortly produced on Chessmetrics so we can compare Firouzja's achievement.

EDIT: note that 100% pointscore results are generally excluded from discussions of TPR because the estimation cannot follow normal elo methods and is done by a separate and little-validated heuristic.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the information in last reply, There are also [Wesly So](http://chess-results.com/tnr60057.aspx?art=9&lan=1&fed=PHI&turdet=YES&flag=30&snr=7) 3183 and [Karen Grigoryan](http://chess-results.com/tnr459618.aspx?lan=1&art=9&fed=ARM&flag=30&snr=1)  3103. But the level of the tournaments are not as sophisticated as Caruana and Firouzja case.

Comment: I would not consider 100% results as the TPR can be considered slightly ill-defined in those cases.

Comment: Welcome to Chess.SE. Besides what 'Stockfish' points out (which I've added to my answer), note that Wesley So's performance you mention is in blitz. By "standard" I took Brian Towers to mean classical only.

Comment: @MobeusZoom thank you. And you guys are absoloutly correct :)